# Merging two tables in one database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've made this employee information system where employees can give their own feedbacks. Here's what it looks like:

[EIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlxNd.png)

When you click the "Employee Feedbacks" button it would redirect you to this page:

[Employee Feedback Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adCus.png)

Now I have 2 tables in my database, the employee and tbl_feedback:

[DB tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsAAv.png)

The problem is with the different ID's. How do I merge the two?

For the employee table:

[employee table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxv0g.png)

For the tbl_feedback:

[tbl_feedback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oalCK.png)

What I want to happen is for the full name to automatically show up when the user clicks on "Employee Feedback". I think that would only be possible if I merge the two tables.

I don't know what source code you guys need but just tell me and I will provide. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: If the employee can only ever make one single feedback comment forever, then yeah you only need one table. But that sounds unrealistic. What you probably want is for your feedback table to have a foreign key relationship to your employee table, based on the employee's unique ID. Then the employee can leave lots of feedback over time, and you can easily relate it to the employee. This is normal relational database design, I suggest you read about it, I think you haven't understood this concept.

Comment: @ADyson That's exactly what I wanted to happen but how do I combine objects from one table to another?

Comment: First decide yourself, where do you want the logic to be written, in stored procedure or in server side program? And to answer your question, there needs to be something common in both the table, so that you can merge it. I guess you can use Email field for that.

Comment: In the meantime, your table structure doesn't specifically prevent you from displaying the employee's name on screen (note _displaying_, they should not need to re-type it, or even be allowed to as part of that form, it should be read-only). You just need to pass the employee ID to the querystring of the feedback page and use that to get the right employee record from the database, and use the name which comes from it. Then you can also use that ID in a hidden field to associate the record in the form with the right employee - you'll get that back when the form's submitted.

Comment: @ADyson Should I make the ID a foreign key? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: "how do I combine objects from one table to another". You don't need to combine anything, you need to create a relationship between the tables based on the employee ID. Again, if you don't understand this basic concept you need to go and study it before you go any further. Once you do, the rest of my comments should make sense.

Comment: Yes, you should make the ID a foreign key. That's why I said "have a foreign key...based on the employee's unique ID"... :-)

Comment: I understand the entity relationship I just don't know how to do it or apply on 
phpmyadmin @ADyson

Comment: In that case read the phpMyAdmin help to find what to click on, or learn how to do it using simple SQL statements instead of the GUI. For that I can't teach you anything which isn't already available in the documentation of MySQL and/or phpMyAdmin

Comment: @ADyson Can you just teach me how do I set the id column in tbl_feedback to foreign key? I keep on getting tutorials with older versions of phpmyadmin so I'm having a hard time figuring it out

Comment: TBH I don't use phpMyAdmin, so I don't know that tool specifically. I write SQL statements or use MySQL Workbench when I interact with MySQL. I imagine it's somewhere in the table editor. It's a common task, it can't be hidden too much. Or just look up the SQL syntax.

Comment: But you don't want to set the ID in the feedback table to be a foreign key, you need to add a new column for Employee ID and make _that_ the foreign key. ID is the unique identifier for Feedback records, and that's fine, don't change it. But it doesn't map to the Employee, and it can't ever do so because you're allowing the employee to insert multiple feedback records if they like, yet the Feedback ID itself must be unique and presumably is auto-generated. Perhaps you haven't actually fully understood the relationship concept yet?

Answer (score 0):

Do, please, have a look at the good advice from @Pete because that will help us to help you.

Here is just a hint about how you use primary and foreign keys to link your tables:

```
create table employee
(
    id         integer,
    fullname   varchar(64),
    username   varchar(32),
    email      varchar(128),
    address    varchar(512),
    contact    varchar(16),
    gender     varchar(16),
    password   varchar(32),
    constraint primary_key_employee primary key (id)
);


create table feedback
(
    id           integer,
    employee_id  integer,
    website      varchar(128),
    message      varchar(2048),
    constraint primary_key_feedback primary key (id),
    constraint foreign_key_feedback_employee foreign key (employee_id) references employee (id)
);

select 
    a.fullname,
    a.email,
    b.website,
    b.message
from
    employee a
    join 
    feedback b
    on a.id = b.employee_id;
```

There are various things that you could improve in you tables (no clear passwords, for example).  That's not intended to be mean, you're clearly making a start, and thinking about what you need, and that's good.  I would suggest that you invest a little time in understanding how SQL databases work.  There is a free resource at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp.  I have tried to offer practical explanations that you can find [here](http://www.thedatastudio.net), and there are many other resources.

I hope it goes well for you.